# MongoDB Atlas as an AWS DMS source endpoint

Tags: mongodb, aws-dms

I'm trying to replicate data from MongoDB Atlas into an S3 data lake (not mongo's data lake) using AWS Data Migration Services, but I'm getting this error:

> Failed to establish a connection to MongoDB using the following parameters: 'mongodb://mongodb+srv://[theUsername]:[thePassword]@[theServer].mongodb.net:27017/?retryWrites=false'

I'm putting this as the Server Name, and DMS is automagically adding the port number from a separate field in DMS and the `retryWrites` param at the end:

> mongodb+srv://[theUsername]:[thePassword]@[theServer].mongodb.net

Anyone successfully used Atlas as a source endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon,

I was able to successfully configure the connection between DMS and MongoDB-Atlas. Both publicly and privately.

As of today, DMS does not officially support MongoDB-Atlas.

For the connection to work, it will be necessary to specify the MongoDB-Atlas primary endpoint in the connection.

Example (endpoint settings):

```
{
     "Username": "username",
     "ServerName": "primary-endpoint.mongodb.net",
     "Port": 1012,
     "DatabaseName": "dbname",
     "AuthType": "password",
     "AuthMechanism": "scram-sha-1",
     "NestingLevel": "none",
     "ExtractDocId": "false",
     "AuthSource": "admin"
}
```

**Important:** The default port changes. Check the port.

To find the endpoints and ports, run the script:
https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/srv-connection-strings/

Finally, enable SSL as Require.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting server, username, and password from the connection string of MongoDB and put these fields separately during endpoint creation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the response from my devops folks was "due to our network config this will never work."